# How to avoid new line in this table td

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

From the image below I want to show the Hallticket in one line. The first one is directly coming from the database. The second one is appending from javascript. How can I display the data all in one line?

[image]

```
<td><b>Hallticket</b> : S24J85 </td>
<td><b>Hallticket </b>: S<p class="hallticketNumber"></p>J'+jobID+' </td>
```

```js
$(this).closest('tr').find(".hallticketNumber").text(ui.item.student_pid);
```

Comment: Add `.hallticketNumber {display: inline; margin: 0;}` in styles.

Comment: `22` student id and `85` job id

Comment: Use a `span` instead of a `p`?

Comment: try to use `<span class="hallticketNumber"></span>` instead of `<p class="hallticketNumber"></p>`

Comment: Thank you i got the solution thanks for support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `HTML` elements can be of two types:

1. Inline Elements (Browser draws them from left to right on screen).
2. Block Elements (Browser draws them from top to bottom - They take full available width).

**Why you have line breaks?**

In the following code:

```
<td><b>Hallticket </b>: S<p class="hallticketNumber"></p>J'+jobID+' </td>
```

`<p>` is a block level elements. Block level elements always start from a new line. And any content after them goes to new line as well.

**What is the solution?**

Two possible ways to solve this are:

1. Use an inline element like `<span>`, `<em>`, `<strong>` etc etc..
2. Use styles and make block level element to behave like inline elements by using `display` css property.

   ```
   .hallticketNumber {display: inline; margin: 0;}
   ```

> Note: As `<p>` element have some default margin in all browsers so it
>   is necessary to reset this.

Answer (score 5):

Either change the `p` element to a `span` to prevent the line break:

```
<td><b>Hallticket</b> : S24J85 </td>
<td><b>Hallticket</b> : S<span class="hallticketNumber"></span>J' + jobID + ' </td>
```

Alternatively, set the `display` of the `p` to `inline` in your CSS:

```css
table td p { display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `span` instead of `p` tag

It should be like this

```
<td><b>Hallticket </b>: S<span class="hallticketNumber"></span>J'+jobID+' </td>
```